# Uglifyjs works from the command-line, but not from npm run script?

Tags: node.js, npm, uglifyjs, package.json, npm-scripts

In my package.json file I have this script:

```
"scripts": {
      "uglify:dist": "uglifyjs ./src/*.js -o ./build/js/app.min.js"
}
```

When I run the script from the command-line it does not create the`app.min.js` file, but only displays the output on the screen

```
$ npm run uglify:dist

> @ uglify:dist /home/user/Desktop/my-github-page
> uglifyjs ./src/*.js -o ./build/js/app.min.js

(function(){"use strict";angular.module("app",["fullPage.js","app.routes","app.footer.directive","app.nav.controller","app.nav.directive","app.main.controller","app.home.controller","app.home.directive","app.about.controller","app.about.directive","app.contact.controller","app.contact.directive","app.projects.controller","app.projects.directive"])})();
```

However, when I run uglifyjs directly from the command line like this, it works!

`$ uglifyjs src/*.js -o build/js/app.min.js`

**I have tried:**

- different variations of the script
- making sure `./build/js` exists
- uninstalling and reinstalling uglify-js
- deleting node modules and rerunning `npm install`

**Versions**

- npm: 4.1.2
- uglify-js: 1.3.5
- node: 7.2.1

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct, just update uglify-js to the latest version.

Comment: I know this is a bit outdated - but I'm struggling the same problem you had. Unfortunately the latest version didn't help for me. When executing the command the file is created. But when running `npm run` or `npm run script` the job isn't done. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`npm run *` command uses local modules in `/node_modules`, so you should install `uglifyjs` into there, like this: `npm install --save-dev uglifyjs`.